# How Does Independence Affect Cardinality?

Tags: probability

I am currently reviewing materials for my upcoming statistics midterm. On one of the examples, it states:

Let $ A = \{ 1,3,5 \} $ and $ P(A) = \dfrac{1}{2} $, where $ A $ is the event that a die is odd.

The question is:

> Is it possible to have an event $ B $ where $ B $ and $ A $ are independent and $ P(B) = \dfrac{1}{2} $?

The answer states that this is impossible because $ |AB| = 1.5 $ (which breaks the law that states that the cardinality of all events must be in the range $ 0 \leq x \leq 1 $). Why is $ |AB| = 1.5 $? The answer explains this by using the intersect $ P(AB) = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{4} $. How does this imply that the cardinality of the set is $ 1.5 $, however?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Candy. I just helped you to enclose all mathematical expressions within ‘$’ signs. This improves the appearance of your post by a huge amount.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep this in mind for next time.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused - the law is not that the cardinality of events must be in the range $0\leq x\leq 1$; that's the rule for the _probability_ of an event.  I think the rule you want (as explained in Brian Scott's answer) is that the cardinality of your event set (as the cardinality of any set) must be a _whole_ number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $6$ possible outcomes are equally likely. If $A$ and $B$ were independent, the probability of getting $B$ given that you have $A$ would be $\frac12$, so exactly half of the outcomes in $A$ would also be in $B$. But $A$ contains $3$ outcomes, and half of $3$ is $1.5$, exactly $1.5$ of the outcomes in $A$ would also be in $B$. Outcomes are indivisible, however, so this is impossible.

Another way to say the same thing is that if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then the probability of getting $A$ **and** $B$ is, as you say, $\frac14$. Since the outcomes of rolling the die are equally likely, this means that exactly $\frac14$ of them are in both $A$ and $B$. But $\frac14\cdot6=1.5$, and again this is impossible: there isn’t such a thing as half an outcome.